# How to get the mid of 2 int32 number elegantly without overflow?

Tags: math, mathematical-expressions

In some conditions like Segment Tree or Binary Search, I have to get the average value of 2 number.

An easy solution is `mid = (a + b) / 2`. But when it comes to `a` and `b` have the same plus-minus signs, The `a + b` thing will overflow. For example, `1234567 + 2147483647`, `-1234567 + (-2147483647)` in int32 type.

I searched online and got to know `mid = (b - a) / 2 + a`, it can avoid the situation above, but still not perfect. When it comes to `a` and `b` have the different plus-minus signs, `mid = (a + b) / 2` won't overflow but `(b - a) / 2 + a` will. For example, `-2147483648 + 2147483647` in int32 type.

To thoroughly solve this problem, I've written the code in pic below. I divide the 2 situations by the plus-minus signs. (I use some bit operations to improve its efficiency.) But it is way too complex for such a simple problem, right?

Is there some elegant solution to this problem?

[image: My Solution Code]

I tried to divide the problem to 2 situations and solve them respectively.
But I still want a more elegant solution.

Comment: Either use a wider integral type if one is available, or if it's so much a concern, maybe `return a/2+b/2+((a&1)&&(b&1))?1:0; `

Comment: In what programming language do you want the solution to be? Why do you have `java`, `c++`, and `c` tags simultaneously?

Comment: Since neither C nor C++ has a `>>>` operator, you can't be asking about these languages.  Tags removed.

Comment: I added 3 languages tags just to get the solution in any one of them, because the elegant solution must be simple enough, so it can be used in any language, that is just a whatever stuff. Funny you remove my tags just because C and C++ don't have ">>>" operator. What you said is right, but don't you know it can be transferred to "if (((a ^ b) >> 31 & 1) == 1) " easily???  If you can solve the problem, solve it. If not, why not just leave and not disturb others?

Comment: @CaryZheng That would've been worth mentioning in the question itself, along with the omission of any specific language tags.

Comment: @cpigeon You're right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the answer!

`mid = (a & b) + ((a ^ b) >> 1)`

`a & b` keeps the same bits that a and b have in common, they need not to be distributed averagely. Like when you find the average value of `102` and `110`, you don't need to calculate the `100` they have in common. You can just keep that, and deal with the `2` and `10` part, distribute them averagely to 2 number. As `(102 + 110) / 2 = (2 * 100 + 2 + 10) / 2 = 100 + (2 + 10) / 2 = 100 + 6 = 106`.

`(a ^ b) >> 1` deals with the "`2` and `10` part", it gets all the bits that a and b don't have in common, and divide it by 2.

Adds up 2 parts above so we get the average value of a and b. Not a strict proof, though.